# Leafletjs reduce tile requests on panning

Tags: leaflet

I use leafletjs combined with my own tileserver. A lot of requests a second use a lot of performance, nothing new about that. But I noticed that if you pan the map real fast, the map is not even drawn, but all the tiles are requested. Take you mouse and swing the map away, you see the map become gray, but in the background, all the tiles are requested.

Simple question, is there no way to create a small timeout on tile requests. That they are only loaded when the map stops moving?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer-updatewhenidle

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I did not see this option! I see TileLayer inherits GridLayer, so I could just add this option and it works, great.